# how do I fade a tikz image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-node, tikz-graphdrawing

I have the following MWE. and I want to fade this square, the caption and everything that I will put in the square.

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
% % % % % Rectangle Model 
    \node (sensor) at (-6.5,-10){};
    \node (sensor_rect1) at (-4.25,-7.25){};
    \node (sensor_rect2) at (-8.75,-12){};
    \draw[line width=2pt,rounded corners=1cm] (sensor_rect1) rectangle (sensor_rect2);
    \node at (-6.5,-10.5) {\textbf{content  here}};
    \node at (-6.5,-12.25){\textbf{  model}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you'd like the whole diagram to have some degree of transparency, so you can see what is behind it?

Comment: @DavidPurton yes i have several of these boxes. so on each beamer slide, i will highlight some boxes and fade others to show I'm not discussing them.

Comment: In a similar spirit to the answer below it might be possible to use `\begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=0.1]`.

Comment: Actually, I notice you say you have several dragams in your `tikzpicture`. Wrap them in `\begin{scope}[opacity=0.1] ... \end{scope}`

Comment: excellent. exactly what i wanted. thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comments, you want to fade parts of a `tikzpicture` in order to highlight  one part.

You can wrap part of your diagram in a scope with a specified opacity:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (sensor) at (-6.5,-10){};
  \node (sensor_rect1) at (-4.25,-7.25){};
  \node (sensor_rect2) at (-8.75,-12){};
  \draw[line width=2pt,rounded corners=1cm] (sensor_rect1) rectangle (sensor_rect2);
  \node at (-6.5,-10.5) {\textbf{content  here}};
  \node at (-6.5,-12.25){\textbf{  model}};
  \begin{scope}[opacity=0.2]
    \node (sensorb) at (0,-10){};
    \node (sensorb_rect1) at (2.25,-7.25){};
    \node (sensorb_rect2) at (-2.75,-12){};
    \draw[line width=2pt,rounded corners=1cm] (sensorb_rect1) rectangle (sensorb_rect2);
    \node at (0,-10.5) {\textbf{content  here}};
    \node at (0,-12.25){\textbf{  model}};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Exactly!. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`\begin{tikzpicture}[color=gray!10]`

Comment: I do not think this will do what the OP wants. What if there is an image in the box content? Or what if some of the text in the box is given an explicit colour? In this case your answer will not work.

Comment: this does not work. cuz in the tikzpicture i have several diagrams. so I want control. I would like to fade some boxes. and and leave others.

Comment: With my suggestion I have the same result as the answer of David Purton! Verify.

Comment: Yes it does the same job. just that it affects all whole tikzpicture whereas i wanted to specify which square in my tikzpicture will be faded or not. Thanks for your input too!